# all else if are triggered despite the fact that first elseif statement is true in first place

Tags: php

all else if are triggered despite the fact that first elseif statement is true in first place.
the first elseif condition met when $user=$first and yet it ignores this and triggers last else,, any ideas?

```
<?php
$user = "205";
$first = "205";
$second = "205";

if ($first === ""){ echo "Nothing  Set <br />"; }
elseif ($user === $first){echo "first was a match<br />";}
elseif ($second === ""){ echo "second was empty <br />"; }
elseif ($user === $second){echo "second was a match <br />";}       
else    {echo "All above must be false <br />";}
       
?>
```

i want if to match only and only one of the conditions, on contrary its matching all.

Comment: Works fine here :) https://3v4l.org/QCP7B

Comment: "All else if are triggered": thats not possible, this code works fine. I would suggest formatting your code a little better. that way debugging will be easier

Comment: @RiggsFolly and Gert-B the value 205 is just for reference, it was fetching from database, error was in matching fetched value, propagated in above results.
Thanks for quick reply, i didn't realize pin point until i saw  3v4l.org/QCP7B , thanks for it. Highly appreciate